# Blender: When resizing the body of the model, the eyes are not affected

Tags: mesh

Someone has any idea how to solve this?

In the 3D model i'm working on, I put a "constraint to" on the eyeballs, so they could be part of the body. But when i'm resizing it, the size of the eyes stays the same.

Any suggestions?

[image: Before Scaling]

[image: After Scaled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your armature can have a  bone to the eyes so that when the armature is scaled so are the eyes.  Create one or two eyeball bones which are connected to the head bone or neck bone.  Thus when you scale armature master bone to scale the fish body, the eyeball bone will scale too.

These are typical settings for the eyeball bone.

Verify the inherit rotation and inherit scale settings.

[image]

[image]

You can have the eyes use a single bone of the armature as [Bone] (object) parent.  So that means no weight painting is necessary.  Thus the bone is behaving like an [empty] in the relationship of being a parent to the eyes.

Comment: Please check out the [style guide](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250/guidelines-on-the-usage-of-stackexchange-markup-and-style) for some guides on formatting your answers.